# Refresh the jquery Data table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two tables having ids Tab1 and Tab2 resp.

What I am doing through code:

On onclick event of a Button one row of Tab2 is deleted and added to Tab1.Initially Tab1 contains no Data thats why in Tab1 table we have the message "No Data Available" using the below code:

```
            this.oLanguage = {
            "sProcessing": "Processing...",
            "sLengthMenu": "Show _MENU_ entries",
            "sZeroRecords": "No matching records found",
            "sEmptyTable": "No Data Available",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Loading...",
            "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ entries",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtered from _MAX_ total entries)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sSearch": "Search:",
            "sUrl": "",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "First",
                "sPrevious": "Previous",
                "sNext":     "Next",
                "sLast":     "Last"
            },
            "fnInfoCallback": null
        };
```

But when one row is added to Tab1, itäs fine but it still showing the message "no data Available". That means table is not get refreshed.

I have following code in javascript:

```
var oTable1=null;
    var oTable2=null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    oTable1 =$('#tab1').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "aSort": false
    }); 

     oTable2 =$('#tab').dataTable( {
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false
} );


    });
```

What should I do to refesh the table so that after adding the data it should not show the message "No data Available"?

Comment: are you adding your row with : http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/add_row.html

Comment: No.I am adding the row using appendChild function in javascript .Firstly I make the clone node of the clicked row of table tab2 and then append this clone node to the table tab1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `oTable.fnAddData` method to add new row.

Use `oTable.fnDraw` method to call redraw method.